# C# convert complicated string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I would like to convert the following string to `DateTime`:

```
string start = "Wed Apr 27 2016 04:00:00 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
        string dateTimeString = "Wed Apr 27 2016 04:00:00 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)";
        string formatString = @"ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss ""GMT""zzz ""(Jerusalem Daylight Time)""";
        var parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, formatString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToLocalTime();
```

I stuck `ToLocalTime()` on the end so there's less confusion about what timezone it returns. Anything between double-quotes is a literal, everything else is a [DateTime Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that `zzz` is the UTC offset, not necessarily the GMT offset, but apparently GMT and UTC are effectively the same thing, so the code should be correct.

Comment: I got an exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: The code I posted works fine. All of your strings must not be the same; if they look like the `dateTimeString` in my post then the code will work. If you want to post the string that isn't working then I can figure it out for you.

Comment: I'm guessing that not all values end in `(Jerusalem Daylight Time)`.